# Как запустить любой скачанный из GIT HUB проект VUE?

Tags: vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я пока изучаю Vue по учебнику и скачал пример кода из книги, но как его запустить для редактирования?
из того что нашлось на просторах:

```
Кроме этого, вы можете запустить пустой проект vuejs, добавить компоненты в ваш проект и импортировать их:
import AndOr from './components/AndOr.vue'
import Rule from './components/Rule.vue'
А потом

Vue.use('AndOr');
Vue.use('Rule');
До запуска приложения Vue
```

перенес package.json
далее запустил npm install
далее  npm run serve
... и ошибок куча не запустился локал хост

Comment: а в package.json что?

Comment: package.json также перекинул на пустой проект, и он не запустился

Comment: вот на первом скрине я приложил, ошибка такая есть - npm ERR! missing script: serve

Comment: package.json выложить ?

Comment: Странный прожект. У моего vue другие папки. Создан через vue create app

Comment: Хорошо как запустить любой скачанный из GIT HUB проект VUE? кто нибудь ведь так делал пока учился кодить??

Comment: @ЭддиВсё, нет. Свои писали заново, но тоже отличная практика. Возможно там есть другой скрипт, `start` или `dev`.

Comment: Нет. Зачем скачивать всякое, перепечатывать из книжек? Сами видите - оно не работает:) Больше проблем вызывает, чем обучает.

Answer (score 4):

Я нашел как правильно запустить проет. Не нужно создавать пустой проект и переносить туда компоненты.

1. в скачаной папке проекта выполнить npm install
2. выполнить npm run dev, т.к. проект создавался еще на старой версии Vue

Answer (score 2):

Хочу предложить альтернативный вариант. Конечно, важно уметь разворачивать проекты локально. Но если нет возможности поставить node.js и необходимо быстро посмотреть пример, то можно воспользоваться сервисом https://codesandbox.io

Копируете URL Github-репозитория, нажимаете "Create SandBox", указываете с какого репозитория импортировать исходный код и нажимаете "Import and Fork"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]